# Dependency injection without using spring framework

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a rather naive question. Can we inject dependencies using core java just like how we inject using Spring framework?

For now, I do something like this:

In web.xml:

```
<context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

spring applicationcontext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="mybean" class="com.test.app.MyService" />

</beans>
```

Class where I will use the injected bean:

```
public class MyResource {

    @Autowired
    private MyService mybean;

     public MyResponse doService(MyRequest req) {
           mybean.doBusiness(req);
     }
}
```

}

So, is there a way we can do this dependency injection using core java? I have been reading a bit on CDI but didn't understand it well. Plus, it also felt like it was not a direct substitution of what Spring does.

Please help and correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "core Java"? That's not a generally-recognized term.

Comment: i changed the title. is it more appropriate?

Comment: That's easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

`javax.inject` (JSR-330) and CDI (JSR-299, JSR-346) are just APIs, not implementations. There are implementations of these APIs that do work in Java SE (as opposed to Java EE, which I suppose is what you mean by "core Java"), e.g. [Weld SE](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#d0e5727).

CDI builds upon JSR-330.

While `javax.inject` is only about basic injection and does not address scopes and lifecycles, it is fair to say that CDI and Spring Core are more or less equally powerful. Both can be used in Java SE.

Answer (score 2):

@Autowired is a Spring annotation that is not standardized. The corresponding standard annotation is @Inject from javax.inject

Aside from Spring, [Google Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) supports also javax.inject

Another extremely lightweight framework for dependency injection (that does not support javax.inject) is [PicoContainer](http://picocontainer.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Dependency injection is a pattern. What you want, and what Spring is at the base, is an Inversion of Control container.

**No, Java SE and Java EE do not provide such an Inversion of Control container.**

Java EE does provide an API in the form of [CDI](http://cdi-spec.org/) for dependency injection. There is a reference implementation called [Weld](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/download/) that you can use.

The other answers list a number of other IoC containers.

Answer (score 2):

You can also look at HK2, which is a full JSR-330 and runs in base JDK.  It has features for the base JDK such as security.  See more here:

[HK2 Main Page](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to have a look at [javax.inject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/package-summary.html). The API is available as a separate jar and a few dependency injections framework exist which depend on, and use, this jar.

Among them are [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and the more lightweight [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/).

Your `@Autowired` here would be `@Inject` in javax.inject language; the two frameworks above allow injection in pure Java (maybe others, don't know because not interested).

Hope this helps...

Comment: Spring also supports `@Inject`.

Comment: I've heard that; however, since when? Spring predates javax.inject.

Comment: Since at least 3.1. Spring's added support for most of the Java EE annotations; for example, it supports all the lifecycle annotations as well. It treats `@Inject` just the same as `@Autowired`, except that `@Inject` doesn't have a `required` option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! [JSR 330](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330) completely talks about this.

You can also take a look at the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch03s09.html).

Comment: actually this is specification aka standard, not real implementation. So  this is not proof that you can use DI in vanilla Java :)     

Spring, Dagger, Guice etc is implementations that one can use for DI.